# How to color odd list items in nested list?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I got the following json

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "sorts": [
        { "name": "green", "number": "6", "comment": "green apples are nice" },
        { "name": "yellow", "number": "1" },
        { "name": "red", "number": "2" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "banana",
      "sorts": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pear",
      "sorts": [
        { "name": "green", "number": "6", "comment": "green pears are sour" },
        { "name": "purple", "number": "0", "comment": "so far we haven't seen purple pears" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is result I want:
[image]

I created this with 2 nested list and passing the name to the nested list.

This works well, but now I want to color the odd list items. That would be the Yellow Apples and Green Pears. I found some example on how to do that on a simple list, but I have a nested list so that won't work.

JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <subDataset name="DatasetFruits">
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[data]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="sorts" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="sorts"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sorts]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DatasetFruitsSort">
        <parameter name="FRUIT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[data.sorts]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="number" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="number"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[number]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="comment" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="comment"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comment]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="43" width="595" height="30"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetFruits">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("data")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="595">
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{sorts}.equals("[]")]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list>
                                <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetFruitsSort">
                                    <datasetParameter name="FRUIT_NAME">
                                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                    </datasetParameter>
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("sorts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="595">
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{FRUIT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                    <textField>
                                        <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                        <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="190" height="30"/>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Your current report/JRXML would be a good starting point for finding a way to do it.

Comment: @dada67 I added the jrxml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JasperReports 6.3.1 or newer, the simplest solution is to switch to JSONQL and use a single list instead of nested lists.  You can read about JSONQL data sources [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html).

With JSONQL you can have a single list that iterates over all `data.sorts.*` nodes and get the fruit name via a field that goes up the tree.  Then with a single list you can have a simple conditional style to color odd rows.

The whole thing would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="af456afc-4615-4564-8841-81929ce2447f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
    <style name="listRow">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} % 2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF00"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="DatasetFruitsSortAll" uuid="5961129e-70f0-4d98-8d4e-524f2bbb28f9">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
        <queryString language="JSONQL">
            <![CDATA[data.sorts]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="fruitName" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^.name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fruitName]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="number" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="number"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[number]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="comment" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="comment"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comment]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="JSONQL">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c4206620-ee0d-4e50-9336-1e1be2723c6f"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetFruitsSortAll" uuid="b9df9d8f-7ada-47eb-84e6-4870547e7bd9">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("data.sorts.*")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="595">
                        <frame>
                            <reportElement style="listRow" x="0" y="0" width="590" height="30" uuid="3b3fba3d-e4c5-499c-a752-b6caa847a448"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="bd3ac2b2-1803-4e0f-afa8-a0bdcc54e6fb"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fruitName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="be871dcb-61a0-49bd-b565-af8aa27bc7f4"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="190" height="30" uuid="bea6dae7-bca2-4c0a-a0b5-443a859c20ac"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </frame>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

If for some reason JSONQL or a single list do not suit you, you can color odd rows with nested lists by having a running row number in the nested list.  To do that you'd need to pass the value forth and back to/from the nested subdataset via a parameter and a return value.

This is how the whole report would look like.  The nesting subdataset has a variable called `subRowCount` which keeps the row count of the previous nested subdataset runs.  The variable is passed to the nesteed subdataset via a parameter; the subdataset adds it to the current row number and uses the result in the conditional style.  Then the final row count is returned back into the `subRowCount` variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="af456afc-4615-4564-8841-81929ce2447f">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
    <style name="listRow">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{runningRowCount} % 2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFF00"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="DatasetFruits" uuid="5824cf79-a97e-4cf1-954b-cc0c327c8405">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[data]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="sorts" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="sorts"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sorts]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <variable name="subRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="System">
            <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
        </variable>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="DatasetFruitsSort" uuid="5961129e-70f0-4d98-8d4e-524f2bbb28f9">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Adapter"/>
        <parameter name="FRUIT_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="prevRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString language="JSON">
            <![CDATA[data.sorts]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="number" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="number"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[number]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="comment" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="comment"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comment]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <variable name="runningRowCount" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$P{prevRowCount} + $V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="43" width="595" height="30" uuid="da841d21-e910-4ce3-b415-1c68cade0981"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetFruits" uuid="4baf7682-130d-4b12-a973-8ab6084373de">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("data")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="595">
                        <componentElement>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="595" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="c4206620-ee0d-4e50-9336-1e1be2723c6f">
                                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$F{sorts}.equals("[]")]]></printWhenExpression>
                            </reportElement>
                            <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetFruitsSort" uuid="b9df9d8f-7ada-47eb-84e6-4870547e7bd9">
                                    <datasetParameter name="FRUIT_NAME">
                                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                    </datasetParameter>
                                    <datasetParameter name="prevRowCount">
                                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{subRowCount}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                    </datasetParameter>
                                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("sorts")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                                    <returnValue fromVariable="runningRowCount" toVariable="subRowCount"/>
                                </datasetRun>
                                <jr:listContents height="30" width="595">
                                    <frame>
                                        <reportElement style="listRow" x="0" y="0" width="590" height="30" uuid="3b3fba3d-e4c5-499c-a752-b6caa847a448"/>
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="bd3ac2b2-1803-4e0f-afa8-a0bdcc54e6fb"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{FRUIT_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                        <textField>
                                            <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="be871dcb-61a0-49bd-b565-af8aa27bc7f4"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                            <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="190" height="30" uuid="bea6dae7-bca2-4c0a-a0b5-443a859c20ac"/>
                                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comment}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                        </textField>
                                    </frame>
                                </jr:listContents>
                            </jr:list>
                        </componentElement>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```